# Power Spectral Density and Fast Fourier Transform basic question

Tags: matlab, digital-communications

I am new to signal processing and I am trying to get the basic concepts right.
I have a signal and I performed the `FFT` of the signal in MATLAB. I also did the `PSD` of the signal in MATLAB using the `psd` command.

So I am confused about:

1) When we get the `FFT` of the signal, It's basically showing what frequency components are inside the signal. So it's a plot of frequency against what? It is amplitude in volt right(took the abs value of the signal)? What if I want to plot dbV against frequency should I just do a mag2dB conversion on the abs value? Is the following right?

Code I tried:

```
Fs = 16000;
t = 0: 1/Fs : 2*(Fs-1)/Fs;
y1 = sin(2*pi*500*t );
fshift = (fftshift(fft(y1)));
f = -8000 : 1/2 : 7999;
figure;
plot(f,mag2db(abs(fshift)));
```

2)Now for the `PSD`, I used the dspdata.psd of MATLAB and I get a plot. On the plot, I get my frequency component but the max amplitude (in dB) is not the same as the max amplitude (in dB) of the `FFT` plot. Why is that? Is it because `dsp` is using 10log 10 and mag2dB is using 20 log 10?

3) In the `PSD` plot I am getting two plots one blue one which is quite visible and a green one, smaller in amplitude, what is this green one?

Code below:

```
Fs = 16000;
t = 0: 1/Fs : 2*(Fs-1)/Fs;
y1 = sin(2*pi*500*t );
psd1=spectrum(y1,1024);
hpsd = dspdata.psd(psd1,'Fs',Fs); % Create a PSD data object.
figure;
plot(hpsd); % Plot the PSD
```

Answer (score 1):

The second trace is probably the phase. You can express the spectral density either as a sine term and a cosine term (in phase and out of phase terms) or as a magnitude and phase angle.  In your first example, for your plot you have converted the sin/cos terms into a magnitude, and discarded the phase information.

Yes, log power differs from log voltage by a factor of two.  $ 2 \log{(V)} = \log{(V^2)} $. But different ways of calculating FT and inverse FT, or PSD and inverse PSD, put a constant value of $ \pi $ in different places: If you use different methods of calculation, you sometimes find that you have choosen to normalize the FT differently.